# Unable to retrieve Flare VM packages from myget via Chocolatey on Windows 10

Tags: chocolatey, choco, myget

I am trying to install packages for Flare VM on Windows 10 using Chocolatey, but I'm facing issues with the installation. Could you please help me resolve this problem? Here is the output I receive:

```
Error retrieving packages from source 'https://www.myget.org/F/vm-packages/api/v2':
```

1. Install older version of Chocolatey and I am currently using Chocolatey version 1.4.0 because there are compatibility issues with the newer version, v2. solved this issue https://github.com/mandiant/flare-vm/issues/454 but this one arises.
2. Checked the sources status and its up.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the release of Chocolatey CLI 2.0, Boxstarter is not able to use 'cinst' during its bootstrapping phase any more. - a PR for this has been raised in the Boxstarter repository and already been merged in.

Until a new version of Boxstarter is being released, you best set the environmental variable `chocolateyVersion` to `1.4` in order to explicitly stick to Chocolatey version 1.4 for now.

`$env:chocolateyVersion = '1.4.0'`

see https://github.com/mandiant/flare-vm/issues/454#issuecomment-1573046515